# When you click on the icon, the application crashes

Tags: java, android

When you click on the icon, the application crashes.
If I enter when I first launch the app from home activity to the trash. All OK. Then I add the item to the cart. Also everything is ok. But then returning to home and trying to enter the basket, I get an application crash and the following error

MY CARTACTIVITY

```
package com.example.tucanofood;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.tucanofood.Common.Common;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.rey.material.widget.Button;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import DataBase.Database;
import Model.Order;
import Model.Request;
import ViewHolder.CartAdapter;

public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference requests;

    TextView txtTotalPrice;
    Button btnPlace;

    List<Order> carts = new ArrayList<>();
    CartAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        database =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        requests = database.getReference("Requests");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listCart);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        txtTotalPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        btnPlace = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnPlaceOrder);

        btnPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showAlertDialog();
            }
        });

        loadlistFood();
    }

    private void showAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Noch ein Schritt!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Eingeben deine Adresse");

        final EditText editAdresse = new EditText(Cart.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        editAdresse.setLayoutParams(lp);
        alertDialog.setView(editAdresse);
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("JA", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Request request = new Request(
                    Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                    Common.currentUser.getVorname(),
                    editAdresse.getText().toString(),
                    txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                    carts
                );

                requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .setValue(request);

                new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Vielen Dank, dass Sie Platz bestellen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NEIN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }

    private void loadlistFood() {
        carts = new Database(this).getCarts();
        adapter = new CartAdapter(carts,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        int total = 0;

        for (Order order:carts)
            total += (Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice())) * (Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));

        Locale locale = new Locale("de", "GER");
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

        txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
    }
}
```

MY LOGCAT Error 138 und 72

```
 --------- beginning of crash
         2020-08-21 11:40:51.591 4973-4973/com.example.tucanofood E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
        main
      Process: com.example.tucanofood, PID: 4973
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.example.tucanofood/com.example.tucanofood.Cart}: 
       java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Tucano Espresso Decaf"
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Tucano Espresso Decaf"
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
    at com.example.tucanofood.Cart.loadlistFood(Cart.java:138)
    at com.example.tucanofood.Cart.onCreate(Cart.java:72)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
```

Comment: " java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Tucano Espresso Decaf""

Comment: "Tucano Espresso Decaf" doesn't seem to be a number

Comment: Use the debugger to view what values are used inside your `loadlistFood()` method. A problem occurs while formating or parsing values.

Comment: You can not convert  "Tucano Espresso Decaf" into ```integer```. Because this is ```String```

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann
codeshare.io/5P9O3d 
codeshare.io/2E7wQo

Comment: @Oigen11 Please read this guide on how to [debug an app with Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug). It is an essential skill that you will require.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is at this line:
*`total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));`*

One of `order.getQuantity()` or `order.getPrice()` are not returning the expected result. You get *"Tucano Espresso Decaf"* returned instead of quantity or price.
Review these two methods or post them here so we can take a look.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5P9O3d
https://codeshare.io/2E7wQo

Comment: All right, but you have to check where you set them. Most probably you assign the product name to the price or to the quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with AlertDialog implementation.
Try this once,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9YDJ.png)